# DateTime.ParseExact - iso8601 with time zone offset

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601

I try to convert a string date to a DateTime. I know my string is an ISO8601 format, with an offset time zone.

I try this :

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it does not work in every cases.

**It works** for a negative offset : *2013-12-11T14:36:00-01:00*

**It does'nt work** (catch an exception) for a positive offset : *2013-12-11T14:36:00+01:00*

Am I using DateTime.ParseExact in the correct way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure? Both works on me. http://ideone.com/PUXorY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you have provided works for me without any format specifications.

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("2013-12-11T14:36:00+01:00");
        Debug.Print(d.ToString());
        Debug.Print(d.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
```

You see, in the latter Print, it prints minus 1 hour, as you specified + 1 hour time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I didn't do an url-encoding of my char '+'...... :S

It is used by a REST web service, so when I send *2013-12-11T14:36:00%2B01:00*, it works..!